# Check if process has started

Tags: c#, process

Let's say I have an application, which starts another application (executable) like this:

```
public void StartExternalProcess() 
{
    string path = "D:\MyExecutable.exe";
    Process process = Process.Start(path);
    // Check here, if process has started
}
```

Executing an .exe file is associated with a small delay. How do I know, when this delay is over, an `process` is ready for use (in my case `process` is a locally running http server)?

In other words, how do I (if possible) make my method an `async Task`, instead of `void`?

Comment: Why do you think that making it an `async Task` will accomplish that? I'm not very strong with async programming by *any* means, but I don't see the connection, so I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Impossible. Only the application knows when it is ready for use (whatever that means). I could code an app, say SleepingBeauty, that waits 100 years and then says that it's ready for use.

Comment: For a program with a GUI interface, we can call [Process.WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=netframework-4.7.2) to wait until it is ready (to process user input), but for your case, the only way to check if it is ready from outside is by sending a request and wait for the response...?

Comment: Are you able to change the code of "MyExecutable" to support this?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I am. And by the looks of the other answers, this seems like the only way to do it. I just wondered if non-GUI apps had some sort of native support for being ready and idle.